# IF ELSE header images with ACF Pro, showing wrong image for archive page

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

I'm attemptin to show different header images based on the page a user visits. The code below works great except for is_archive(listings)

For some reason it wants to use the image from is_archive(team)

```
<div class="header-images">
   <?php if (is_archive('team')) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_team', 'options'); ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" />

   <?php } elseif (is_singular('team')) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_team', 'options') ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" /> 

   <?php } elseif (is_archive('listings')) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_listings', 'options'); ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" />

   <?php } elseif (is_singular('listings')) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_single') ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" />

   <?php } elseif (is_home()) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_ic', 'options') ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" /> 
   <?php } ?>
```

For what it's worth, I am using this with Advanced Custom Fields PRO. So I've setup an options page for the custom post types: team & listings. In each post types menu there is a settings panel with the ability to upload an image.

The singular 'listings' pull an image from each post and then of course is_home (the default blog) has an options panel with an image to upload as well.

Overall, If I am not declaring that the archive page for 'listings' is suppose to show the team image, then it shouldn't show anything all, right?

Here's the function for ACF Pro options.

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
  acf_add_options_page(array(
    'page_title'  => 'Theme General Settings',
    'menu_title'  => 'Theme Settings',
    'menu_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
    'capability'  => 'edit_posts',
    'redirect'    => false
  ));

  acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'page_title'  => 'Theme Header Settings',
    'menu_title'  => 'Header',
    'parent_slug' => 'theme-general-settings',
  ));

  acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'page_title'  => 'Theme Footer Settings',
    'menu_title'  => 'Footer',
    'parent_slug' => 'theme-general-settings',
  ));

  acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'title'      => 'Team Settings',
    'parent'     => 'edit.php?post_type=team',
    'capability' => 'manage_options'
  ));

  acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'title'      => 'Listings Settings',
    'parent'     => 'edit.php?post_type=listings',
    'capability' => 'manage_options'
  ));

  acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'title'      => 'Industry Coverage Settings',
    'parent'     => 'edit.php',
    'capability' => 'manage_options'
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few semicolons, also on the elseif-statement previous to `listings`. Perhaps that's your problem.

With correct syntax:

```
<?php } elseif (is_singular('team')) { ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('header_image_team', 'options'); ?>" class="img-responsive bkg" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but adding those semicolons back in didn't solve anything.

Comment: Hm, ok. From what I can tell you must have a bug in your options page code. Read through the ACF documentation and it looks alright.

Comment: I've added the options page code function to my original post. All looks well to me. Maybe you see something I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you havn't a archive.php or achive-your_custom_post.php, Wordpress use index.php to display the page.

Then, it's normal if you don't see the right image.
Cause your in the case is_home().

Comment: I do have two archive pages for 'team' and 'listings'. That's how I am displaying the images on those custom post type archive pages.